# Erro ao gerar release com maven/gitflow

Tags: git, maven, ssh, release

Olá, tenho uma aplicação Java e utilizo o Maven + gitflow para gerar releases. Consigo fazer o clone via ssh/key sem problema. Porém na hora hora de rodar o comando

```
mvn jgitflow:release-start
```

O seguinte erro é lançado:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.UnsupportedCredentialItem:
ssh://git@127.0.0.1:10022: The authenticity of host '127.0.0.1' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 7e:03:51:7b:55:a5:cd:de:4c:7a:0d:1b:43:75:08:68.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting?
      at  com.atlassian.maven.plugins.jgitflow.util.ConsoleCredentialsProvider.get(ConsoleCredentialsProvider.java:71)
```

Se altero o acesso ao git via HTTP o release funciona, mais quero gerar versão e postar a tag no git via ssh/key

Comment: Alguma dica pessoa? algum comando ssh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver, desativei a verificação ssh no Ubuntu

Adicionei a seguinte linha ao meu `~/.ssh/config` (se o arquivo não existir, basta cria-lo)

```
Host *
StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

O `*` desativa para todos os hosts, se você quiser desativar para um host específico, basta substituir o `*` pelo host